# Dual objects in an abelian monoidal category

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, abelian-categories

Let $(\mathcal{M},\otimes)$ be a monoidal category that is also abelian, and assume that $\otimes$ is bilinear with respect to the biproduct. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two objects that admit (left) duals ${}^{\vee}X$, and ${}^{\vee}Y$, respectively. Then does it hold that $X \oplus Y$ admits a left dual and that
$$
{}^{\vee}(X \oplus Y) \simeq {}^{\vee}X  \oplus {}^{\vee}Y?
$$
What does the isomorphism look like explicitly?

Comment: ${}^{\vee}X  \oplus {}^{\vee}Y$ is also a left dual of $X\oplus Y$ (the evaluation is given by $({}^{\vee}X  \oplus {}^{\vee}Y) \otimes (X\oplus Y) \simeq ({}^{\vee}X \otimes X) \oplus ({}^{\vee}Y \otimes Y) \oplus ({}^{\vee}X \otimes Y) \oplus ({}^{\vee}Y \otimes X)$ and applying the evaluation on the first two summands and the zero map on the last to, I think). Then use that duals are canonically unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the sense that the OP is a relatively new user of MO and trying to learn about monoidal abelian categories. While [the comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463612/dual-objects-in-an-abelian-monoidal-category#comment1203670_463612) gives the core idea answering the OP's question, I wanted to point out that this has been [asked before and a lengthy answer written](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864242/is-the-class-of-dualizable-objects-in-an-abelian-monoidal-category-closed-under), really spelling out the isomorphism the OP asks about. That thread is over on MSE = math stack exchange (which might have been a better place to ask the current question). More about duality in monoidal abelian contexts (written at a higher level) can be found in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.03545.pdf).